# When should I use ref classes in C++/CX?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm wading back into the C++ world for a project, and between spending a lot of time with C#, and the new stuff in C++/CX, I'm a bit rusty.

When is it appropriate to use the `ref class` type introduced in C++/CX?

The built-in reference counting handle seems nice and seems like a good reason to use ref classes wherever possible (ignoring portability concerns).  However, I'm unsure if these types add any extra overhead? Or if there's another reason to limit its usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep in mind that C++/CX is a language extension to make dealing with WinRT types easy.  You only have to declare your own *ref class* when you want to make your type usable by another language, like Javascript or C#.  In other words, when you create a WinRT component.

For everything else, which should be the vast majority of your code, use standard C++11 syntax and the normal workhorse C++ standard library classes.  Declaring a ref class that you don't expose to other languages just creates unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks, seems like good advice!  I'm reading now that ref class limits inheritance and adds some interfaces like IDisposable behind the scenes. Not sure if there's other things that effect performance too...